# Activation Layer is stashing 2 attributes from the tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

> TensorFlow version: tf 1.13.1
>   Keras version: 2.2.4
>   Python version: 3.7

After debugging, I see that after adding activation layers at various segments of my model, layer drops 2 attributes _keras_history and _keras_shape.

Currently, the model isn't compiling as my architecture has an activation layer at the end applied after computing logits.

code:

```
x = keras.activations.relu(x)
ff_layer2 = keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D(128, strides=(1, 1), depth_multiplier=1, padding='same')(x)
classifier = keras.activations.softmax(ff_layer2)

x = keras.activations.relu(x)
ff_layer2 = keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D(128, strides=(1, 1), depth_multiplier=1, padding='same')(x)
classifier = keras.activations.softmax(ff_layer2)
```

The error:

```
File "/home/perennial_qube/.conda/envs/fast-scnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 188, in _init_graph_network
    'Found: ' + str(x))
ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("truediv:0", shape=(?, 2048, 1024, 128), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions in `keras.activations.*` are **activation functions**, and not Keras layers. The architecture of models in Keras should only be built with layers. So you need to use their [equivalent activation layers](https://keras.io/layers/advanced-activations/):

```
from keras.layers import Softmax, ReLU

x = ReLU()(x)
# ...
classifier = Softmax()(ff_layer2)
```

Alternatively, you can use the `activation` argument of layers and pass the name or activation function directly. For example:

```
... = DepthwiseConv2D(..., activation='softmax')
# or:
... = DepthwiseConv2D(..., activation=keras.activations.softmax)
```

As another alternative you can use the `Activation` layer and pass the name of activation function:

```
from keras.layers import Activation

# ...
classifier = Activation('softmax')(ff_layer2)
```

The first solution, compared to the two other solutions, has this advantage that you can easily modify the behavior of the activation function by providing custom arguments. For example, by default the softmax activation is computed over the last axis, but if needed you can change this as follow:

```
from keras.layers import Softmax

classifier = Softmax(axis=my_desired_axis)(ff_layer2)
```